# Predicting single floats based on set of 2 feature arrays each of 100 values

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, dataset, lasso

I am trying to predict audio to video desynchronization based on set of two arrays of lenght 100 which consist of coresponding audio and video samples.

The problem is that my labels are single floats (values of shift), while both audio and video data are arrays of lenght 100. So far I tried Lasso for that problem but I couldn't get rid of errors while fitting model.

This is how my data looks like:

```
>> print(audio)
[[0.675324 ... 0.59183673, ] ... [0.34116661 ... 0.12759797]]

>> print(audio.shape)
(200, 100)

>> print(video)
[[0.67532086 ... 0.12184522 ][0.34116661 ... 0.10322892]]

>> print(video.shape)
(200, 100)

>> print(shift)
[ 900  500  ...   50 -250]

>> print(shift.shape)
(200,)
```

Is there any way to do that with that model or maybe there is some other solution to that?

Comment: What do your audio and video features represent?  "couldn't get rid of errors"?  .. Python errors? ... inaccurate results?

Comment: Video feature represent lips separation distance on each frame, audio feature is zero-crossing rate calculated for the time period corespodning to each frame.

Comment: I've never processed data like this, but I wonder if you trained on the concatenation of audio and video for `shift`, could that work?  I.e., use 200 features (100+100) to predict `shift`.  Or is that what you meant by "ser od"?  A spelling mistake?

Comment: That supposed to be 'set of' - edited it now. Thats exactly the way that I am trying to do that. But I don't know how to. Classical machine learning algorithms seems not to work for data with different dimensions as in that case.

Comment: You could create a new concatenated list of features by doing something like `new_features=[x+y for x,y in zip(audio,video)]` and then try your training with the new list.